# Open Office Automation

Tags: delphi, automation, openoffice.org

Really hoping someone here will be able to help me. I am wanting to automate my applications and Open Office.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction? There is mountains of information out there for Microsoft Office Automation but barely anything on Open Office.

I hope someone can recommend a good set of components to purchase or perhaps some good libraries to include in my projects that will make automation easier.

Any help would be appreciated!

Kind Regards

Donovan

Comment: Note: OpenOffice via OleAutomation is an area that is frequently broken (non functional) in the OpenOffice codebase.

Comment: @Warren P: indeed, OpenOffice 3.3 automation is broken. There seems to be a fix for it, but it hasn't been incorporated yet in the 3.4 beta. And with the current drop of OpenOffice by Oracle and Apache taking over the project, I don't know when 3.4 will be released.

Comment: Are there the same problems with LibreOffice 3.3 or are "they" faster with their bugfixes?

Comment: I have not seen a broken codebase with COM and UNO for a long time UNTIL OO 3.3. So I would recommend to use OO 3.2.1. As far as I see, LibreOffice is going to be better maintained than OO. I do have not experiences with LibreOffice until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a lot examples around. In the UNO OpenOffice Project, there are some samples also for Delphi. The samples for other languages are also helpfull, because the systematic of UNO (which is the API of OpenOffice also over COM) is a bit complicated.

There is also a forum with some Delphi-Code: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/

There are some Tools and Constanst and Example Units, this is a very good starting point: http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidB69083385CA27692654E24A4FBC81ED2AC516B49.aspx?s=ftp#L63

I have quite a lot of code for that task, but it is too much to post it here (sorry) and it is included in a very big application.

Answer (score 0):

you can start by checking out the UNO OpenOffice automation project: http://udk.openoffice.org/

There was also a Sun Microsystems initiative called ODF Toolkit, but it never took off.

Comment: The ODF Toolkit project has moved to an Apache incubator.  Most of the work is Java based but I don't think they have gotten into automation areas at this point.  Check out http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/